# Поиск в БД по нескольким условиям

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть БД на которой пытаюсь изучить основы `hibernate`. Написал небольшой класс, описывающий таблицу из БД, в статьях в интернете читал что нужно использовать для работы с БД класс `DAO`, в котором описываются методы работы с БД.

У меня есть таблица users, которая содержит в себе данные о пользователях. Поля `login, description, group` хранят соответственно данные о логине, описание и группа пользователя.

Как обычно реализуется выборка из БД по некоторым условиям? Посмотрев некоторые статьи обнаружил что есть варианты `hibernate search` и что-то типа запроса `createQuery("from Users")`.

Если честно не смог разобраться какой способ в каких случаях нужно выбирать, какой способ быстрее и как вообще реализовать выборку по нескольким условиям.

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать или может быть есть понятный пример.

Answer (score 0):

Можно же на JPQL (HQL) написать все условия, которые нужны.
Пример:

```
select user from User user where login = 'user1' and group = 'USER'
```

Comment: Я так пробовал, только вот не понял как написать такой запрос, который будет работать по параметрам. Например пользователь ввел только логин, а группу не ввел, тогда искать всех пользователей с такими логинами. Еще пользователь может ввести часть логина, тут нужно искать уже всех пользователей, где встречается введенная часть.